# Как разбить строку на подстроки?

Tags: java, строки, arraylist

У меня имеется коллекция `ArrayList` с одной строкой более 10000+ знаков.

```
[81383,892881,381818,54881,1283128...]
```

Из-за этого, я не могу обратится в листе к какому-либо элементу, потому что он один.

Как его разбить таким образом, чтобы вместо одной строки их было столько, сколько всего элементов.

На примере этого листа я хотел бы получить так:

```
81383
892881
381818
54881
1283128
```

Comment: Посмотрите функцию `split`

Comment: Вы пытаетесь распарсить json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Применяете к строке в листе split(), тем самым разбивая строку на массив строк. Потом можете с этим массивом работать или в другой лист записать.

Пример использования:

```
String[] str = list.get(0).split(",");
```

Answer (score 3):

Пусть `defaultArrayList` – исходный список и `defaultArrayList.get(0)` – Ваша длинная строка.

Требуемое можно получить, например, так:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(defaultArrayList.get(0).split(",")));
```

Ключевой момент тут – это метод `split(...)`, который возвращает массив, полученный разделением строки по тому, что Вы в него передаете.